# Facebook login (xcode8) Swift3 Not working

Tags: fbloginview

I try every solution from internet for this problem .

I use : Version 8.0 beta 6 (8S201h)  Swift 3

I setup :

Info.plist from facebook dev site with current app data ,
  AppDelegate ,
  Put FBlogin btn (also try custom FB login btn) ,
  import FB SDK (last) ,
  Single Sign On YES - facebook dev
  set localhost for App domain

I add also web login component (in ios ap i put webview), to try alternative solution . Not working...

Please go to repo :
this is the link of project :

https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/FBLoginSwift3

I post this question on facebook dev help page and they tell me to 
turn on KayChain Sharing . This help me to move from dead point.
*I have some success with fbsdkloginmanager with popup login windows.
After entering email and pass in popup app show -already authorized ... 
I press confirm i got my user name , friends (logged in )etc.*

But this login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.native and native button (delegate) not woking ..

New error log :

-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"

**screenshoot1** :

[image]

This is working code but works slow also error log  and popup(screenshoot1)  are still here :

```
   var login = FBSDKLoginManager()
    // login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.native
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.web
    // login.logOut()
    login.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], from: self ) {
        (loginResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) in

        if (error != nil) {
            print("Process error2")
        }
        else if (loginResult?.isCancelled)! {
            print("Cancelled2")
        }
        else {
            print("Logged in2")
                 self.showUserData()
        }

    }
```

Comment: First remove app from your fb account, then check you give all read permissions and then try.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/help/218345114850283?helpref=about_content

Comment: I try this Max , app just ask me to continue after i got same problem !