# completion handler's error in swift 3 and Xcode 8

Tags: ios, facebook, afnetworking, swift3, xcode8

I have working project in Xcode 7.3 with swift 2.2 version. Now I have updated Xcode 8 and migrated to swift 3. Now my project contains errors specially for blocks like success block of afnetworking.

[image: Snapshot for error in afnetworking post method]

Which gives error as

```
Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '((URLSessionDataTask, Any?) -> Void)?'
```

I don't understand how to solve this to work as per swift 3.

And there is also same like error in Facebook login.

[image: Facebook Login error]

Which gives error as

```
Cannot convert value of type '(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler!'
```

and

```
Cannot convert value of type '(_, _, NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'FBSDKGraphRequestHandler!'
```

This all errors are related to handler blocks in swift 3. I don't understand the errors and so that can't able to solve. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Though I didn't know the error before that what Xcode want to inform me about the error, but I have removed type specification with object and it worked.

As

```
manager.post(methodname, parameters: param, progress: nil, success:{ (dataTask, responseObj) in

                if let dict : NSDictionary = responseObj as? NSDictionary {

                    print("Response of \(methodname) : \(dict)")

                    if dict.object(forKey: "response") as? String == "success" {
                        CompletionHandler(true, dict)
                    } else {
                        CompletionHandler(false, dict)
                    }


                }

        })
```

Here with respect to question error is given at `dataTask` and `responseObj` which are with type specified. After removing type it worked fine.

Same as with facebook login

```
@IBAction func fbLoginClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        app.fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        app.fbLoginManager.logOut()
        app.fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.native


        app.fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            } else {

                if (result! as FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult).isCancelled == true {

                } else {

                    self.fetchFacebookUserDetail()
                }
            }
        })

    }
```

Here also I have removed type specification of `result` and `error` and problem solved. And followed this in whole app and it worked. I can run the project without error and also it is working. Thanks.

Comment: Half of your answer helped me VERY much.
I was hoping you could help me complete the other half.
I have a delegate method that accepts an NSError from objective c, but when I convert it to swift, I cant figure out the syntax, it complains that my class doesnt conform to the protocol it came from...

Comment: @LenaBru Because NSError becomes Error in swift 3, so change your method accordingly.

Comment: to get the userInfo member, I have to cast it "as! NSError" ... this is so horrible...

Comment: @LenaBru. I have faced same. I also need userInfo from NSError because I got response in json from server with error code 400 and json but I can't get those information now by this methods. So I have changed afnetworking to alamofire now.

Comment: I need help : i always get a loginResult?.isCancelled ?

Comment: @NikolaLukic Post a question which shows code what you have done so that you get help to find problem and it's appropriate solution.

Comment: @Max Here is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506833/facebook-login-xcode8-swift3-not-working  i post github project also .

Comment: I'm getting warning of "Expression of type 'URLSessionDataTask?' is unused". Can anyone help?

Comment: @Felix just replace dataTask object with _ (underscore)

Comment: Fixed by adding .resume(). My mistake. Mine is GET request.

Answer (score 14):

For facebook - the problem is in new Swift rules about converting objective-c function parameters into Swift.

Previously, if parameters in objective-c code did not have nullability attributes(like `nonnull` or `nullable`), Swift converts it with `!` making them non optional(forced unwrapping). Now it convert it with `?` making them optional. That why you are getting an error. Before you were putting as a callback for login:

```
(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, NSError!) -> Void
```

Now you need to put:

```
(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, Error?) -> Void
```

Also, as you see, now you will not see `NSError` class. Instead of that Swift will put `Error`.This is also new rule. Now all *"NS"* prefixed in class names is removed in Swift(`NSObject` -> `Object`; `NSError` -> `Error`).

Example of working code for facebook login in Swift 3.0:

```
let manager = FBSDKLoginManager()

manager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile"], from: self.controller) {
    (loginResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) in

}
```

Example of working code for facebook request in Swift 3.0:

```
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest()

request.start {
     (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection?, result: Any?, error: Error?) in

}
```

As you see, now it is using `Any` type instead of objective-c `id`. In Swift 2.2 it was using `AnyObject`. It is also new Swift converting rule.

You do not need to specify callback parameters type. I did that in code for highlighting their real types. So you can just write code without them:

```
let manager = FBSDKLoginManager()

manager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile"], from: self.controller) { (loginResult, error) in }


let request = FBSDKGraphRequest()

request.start { (connection, result, error) in }
```

But you need to remember that they are optional now.

In conclusion some converting rules that may affect you callback code:

1. Closure parameters are optional if in objective-c are not specified nullability attributes
2. All *"NS"* prefixes is removed for objective-c classes in Swift
3. If objective-c function had `id` parameter, in Swift 3.0 it will have type `Any` instead of `AnyObject`

Comment: @Max see code example from my project that is working. I put there also the definition of callback parameters type to show what exactly it is, but it is non necessary.

Comment: Yes I have put same like yours then also error is there. Then I have removed :FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult? and :Error? then error gone.

Comment: @Max try to clean the project. It should work. If no, just check by your self what kind of params it need.

Comment: Trying all the possibilities and solving one by one, There are lots of syntax changes.

Comment: @Max have you managed to solve problem with facebook by changing params to optional?

Comment: Just removed that optional?. Like - handler: { (result, error) -> Void in