# AFNetwoking with swift 3.0 & xcode 8 : POST Request & GET Request

Tags: post, get, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to parse data using AFNetworking & swift 3.0 and xcode 8.0 but i am getting error like below.below code works fine for swift 2.3 but not working in 3.0

**Or if is there anyone know about AFNetworking & swift 3.0 using xcode 8.0 for POST & GET request please tell me. with simple example.
Thanks in Advance**

You can see below error.

[image]

```
 func callApi(apiName: String, param: [String : AnyObject]?, data: NSDictionary?, withMethod type: String, CompletionHandler:@escaping (_ code: Int, _ error:NSError?, _ response:AnyObject?) -> Void)

    {

        MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: AppDelegateObj.window, animated: true)
        let str_URL : String = kHOSTPATH+apiName

        let manager: AFHTTPSessionManager = AFHTTPSessionManager()

        if (type == kREQ_POST) {

            manager.POST(str_URL, parameters: param, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData: AFMultipartFormData!) in

                if data?.allValues.count != 0 && data != nil
                {

                    let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: (data?.valueForKey("filePath"))! as! String)
                    try! formData.appendPartWithFileURL(fileUrl, name: (data?.valueForKey("key"))! as! String)
                }

                }, progress: { (NSProgress) in

                }, success: { (task:URLSessionDataTask, responseObject) -> Void in

                    CompletionHandler(code: 1, error: nil, response:responseObject)
                    MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(AppDelegateObj.window, animated: true)

                }, failure: { (task:URLSessionDataTask?, error:NSError) -> Void in

                    CompletionHandler(code: 0, error: error, response:nil)
                    MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(AppDelegateObj.window, animated: true)
            })
        }
        else {

            manager.GET(str_URL, parameters: param, progress: { (NSProgress) in

                }, success: { (task:URLSessionDataTask, responseObject) -> Void  in

                    CompletionHandler(code: 1, error: nil, response:responseObject)
                    MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(AppDelegateObj.window, animated: true)

                }, failure: { (task:URLSessionDataTask?, error:NSError) -> Void  in

                    CompletionHandler(code: 0, error: error, response:nil)
                    MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(AppDelegateObj.window, animated: true)
            })
        }
    }
```

but i am getting error like this

```
cannot convert the value of type (URLSessionDataTask?,NSError)->Void to expected argument type '((URLSessionDataTask?,NSError)->Void)?'
```

Comment: Please refer the link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508868/completion-handlers-error-in-swift-3-and-xcode-8) which will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your error type from NSERROR to ERROR. Type compatibility changed from Swift2.3 to Swift 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func Get()
{
    let url = NSURL(string: Webserive.UserProfileInfoList + "/" + String(300))
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) {(response, data, error) in
        self.GetData(data: data! as NSData)
    }
}

func GetData(data:NSData){

    let dict: NSDictionary!=(try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
    print(dict)
    self.PostData()
}

func PostData(){

    let parameters : NSMutableDictionary? = [

        "UserID": String(300),
        "UserProfileID": String(356)]

        let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()

        let serializerRequest = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
        serializerRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        manager.requestSerializer = serializerRequest

        let serializerResponse = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
        serializerResponse.readingOptions = JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments
        serializerResponse.acceptableContentTypes = ((((NSSet(object: "application/json") as! Set<String>) as Set<String>) as Set<String>) as Set<String>) as Set<String>;
        manager.responseSerializer = serializerResponse
        manager.post(Webserive.DefaultProfile, parameters: parameters, progress: nil, success: { (task: URLSessionDataTask, responseObject: Any?) in
        if (responseObject as? [String: AnyObject]) != nil {

             print("responseObject \(responseObject)")
        }
    }) { (task: URLSessionDataTask?, error: Error) in
        print("POST fails with error \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Do not know what is the root of the problem but you can help yourself by not specifying some parameter's type, in this case 'error' in POST method call:

```
manager.post("http://...", parameters: [:], progress: nil, success: { (operation: URLSessionDataTask, responseObject: Any?) in
    print("Success")
}, failure: { (operation: URLSessionDataTask?, error) in
    let error = error as? Error
    print("Failure, error is \(error?.description)")
})
```

With this code pattern I can build the code with Xcode 8.3 and Swift 3.

---

EDIT:

If you have some problem with "Cannot convert value of type...", please check type that function expects.

My problem was that I had declaration of Error as CoreData one and AFNetworking certainly does not return that Error type.

```
class Error: NSManagedObject {
// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass
}
```

What I needed to change was:

```
(operation: URLSessionDataTask?, error: Error?)
```

to:

```
(operation: URLSessionDataTask?, error: Swift.Error?)
```