# Reformatting function to swift 3.0 syntax

Tags: swift, swift3, dispatch

Please note that I did not create this function, it is a part of a library that has not been updated by it's creator. Could somebody please give advice as how to switch the function to swift 3.0?

```
func debounce( delay:TimeInterval, queue:DispatchQueue, action: @escaping (()->()) ) -> ()->() {
         lastFireTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,0)
         dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,dispatchDelay),queue) {
         let now = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,0)
         let when = dispatch_time(lastFireTime, dispatchDelay)
         if now >= when {
         action()
         }
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: Remove type of object from method, if it works. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39526497/3463712

Answer (score 0):

C API

```
dispatch_time_t
     dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t base, int64_t offset);

 void
     dispatch_after(dispatch_time_t when, dispatch_queue_t queue,
         void (^block)(void));
```

in Swift, the same functionality is available via Dispatch framework (import Dispatch), which is nice object oriented framework build on top of C API. Try next snippet in you Playground and next check current Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch) for more details.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

import Foundation
import Dispatch

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "my queue")

// call the block asynchronously after some time
print(1, "now is", Date())

queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5)) {
    print()
    print(3, "now is", Date())
    PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
}

print(2, "now is", Date())
```

Good starting point for beginners is [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1)

I suggest you read [A quick look at Grand Central Dispatch and Swift 3](https://medium.com/swift-and-ios-writing/a-quick-look-at-gcd-and-swift-3-732bef6e1838) with a lot of information in the very compressed form.